# How to have useEffect() act like componentDidMount()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am using a functional component and I need to be able to use componentDidMount().  Online I found that through react hooks you can use useEffect() as componentDidMount() in functional components.  However, this is not working as I thought it would.  I was thinking that on page load this would fire but it is not.  Does anyone know how to get useEffect to act like componentDidMount?

```
const Contact = ({
  previousProgressBarNow,
  setPreviousStepValue,
  addPropsToCallback,
  hasSuggestions,
  showSMSOptInCheckbox,
  params,
  sendEnhancedTrackEvent
}) => {
  const enhanceableData = {
    name: 'Item Clicked',
    properties: {
      ...defaultProps,
      activityLocation: 'Member - RAQ Contact Details - useEffect',
      description: 'SMS Opt-In Checkbox',
      autopopulated: true,
      changeType: 'Add',
      href: process.env.IS_BROWSER && typeof window !== 'undefined' ?
          window.location.href : undefined
    }
  };

  // This acts as componentDidMount
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      sendEnhancedTrackEvent(enhanceableData);
    }
  }, []);
```

I tried just simply doing this but then it creates an infinite loops and I get an error:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    sendEnhancedTrackEvent(enhanceableData);
  });
```

And yes I have imported it:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
```

Comment: You're not actually doing anything in your `useEffect()`, you're just immediately cleaning up. Have you tried logging something in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

useEffect works a bit different. 
It receives a function, that can return a cleanup function.

So your code could be:

```
const Contact = ({
  previousProgressBarNow,
  setPreviousStepValue,
  addPropsToCallback,
  hasSuggestions,
  showSMSOptInCheckbox,
  params,
  sendEnhancedTrackEvent
}) => {
  // code

  // This acts as componentDidMount
  useEffect(() => {
    sendEnhancedTrackEvent(enhanceableData);
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const ProvidersContainer = ({getProvidersData}) => {
 const [pageNo, setpageNo] = useState(1);
 useEffect(() => { // Component Did Mount
  getProvidersData(pageNo);
 }, []);
}
```